# Sync with Pardot by Apex Trigger | Duplicate send to Pardot button in Apex

Tags: apex, callout

I have Pardot installed in my SF sandbox and it is connected to a Pardot Sandbox.

[Use Case]: If a prospect is in the recycle bin in Pardot, then it does not sync with Salesforce. If from a Salesforce Contact you manually press the "Sync to Pardot" button, then the prospect is "undeleted"/ removed from the Recycle bin.

I am trying to automate this process by replicating the function of Send To Pardot button in Apex. When clicked on this button, it populates the field "PardotURL" on my Contact and connects it to Pardot.

Code of Send To Pardot button (managed pardot package)

```
/apex/pi__SendToPardot?contactEmail={!URLENCODE(Contact.Email)}&contactId={!Contact.Id}&serverUrl={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_90}
```

> eg. https://cs15.salesforce.com/apex/pi__SendToPardot?contactEmail=abc%40example.com&contactId=00336000012BDEf&serverUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fcs15.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2FSoap%2Fu%2F90.0%2F00De000000B7cmUJH

In all my tries using the Chrome Network tab to debug, here are the things I learned.

> - You can generate the URL and hit it by browser and it works.
> - When you hit the above URL, a 302 status code (redirection) is returned, which redirects to the following URL https://pi.cs15.visual.force.com/apex/SendToPardot?[sameRestOfTheURL], which completes the transaction successfully and makes the connection.
> - You can also directly hit the "pi.cs15.visualforce.com" URL on the browser and it works.

However I am not able to replicate this in Apex. Here is my Apex code which gives a 200 Status Code but does not populate the Pardot fields on Contact and does not make a connection.

> Salesforce documentation on the required [community cloud cookies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_cookie.htm&type=5).

Executing this in Anonymous window:

```
String urlToHit = '';
String contactEmail = 'abc@example.com';
String contactId = '00336000012BDEf';
LoginHistory userLoginHistory = [SELECT UserId, LoginTime , SourceIp ,NetworkId from LoginHistory where UserId =:userinfo.getuserid() order by LoginTime desc limit 1];
String sidClientCookie = Userinfo.getUserId().substring(4,15)+UserInfo.getOrganizationId().substring(4,15);

urlToHit += 'https://pi.cs15.visual.force.com';
urlToHit += '/apex/SendToPardot?';
urlToHit += 'contactEmail='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactEmail,'UTF-8');
urlToHit += '&';
urlToHit += 'contactId='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactId,'UTF-8');
urlToHit += '&';
urlToHit += 'serverUrl='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(),'UTF-8') + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('/services/Soap/u/90.0/','UTF-8') + UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
System.debug('--->'+urlToHit);

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();        
req.setEndpoint(urlToHit);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setTimeout(30000);
req.setHeader('Cookie','sid='+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Cookie','sid_Client='+sidClientCookie);
req.setHeader('Cookie','clientSrc='+userLoginHistory.SourceIp);
req.setHeader('Cookie','BrowserId='+'KGChDtNCQMacTpPLRwtATQ'); // hardcoded browser id | it still does't work though

System.debug('--3->'+req);

HttpResponse res = http.send(req);     
System.debug('--2->'+res);
```

If the response returned is 302 (redirection), it is handled similar to the way given in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11126/how-do-i-handle-a-302-redirect-response-to-my-http-callout) answer.

Comment: Status 200 would indicate: OK. What you want to try: POST the data to that endpoint. You want a 201 (created). Also include your session auth in the header

Comment: are you sure about the URL for the apex to hit? I guess visual.force(or visualforce) is for VF pages(but in this case I think you're trying to hit the same URL of VF.

Comment: @stwissel I do not want to POST the data. According to my understanding, you can only do a GET request from your browser URL bar, hence I am only doing a GET request via. apex. Also if you see my posted code, I am including the session id in the cookie. Please help me if I am wrong.

Comment: @YsrShk Yes, I am sure. I copied the exact URL from the System.debug log and pasted it in browser URL and it worked.

Comment: AFAIK you need an Authorization Header. Cookie won’t do. Your client ip mismatches with the server

Comment: @stwissel I replicated the request with PostMan. It did not work before w/o any cookies. But then I added cookies one by one and it worked for the cookies I have posted (works even w/o browser id).

Comment: Postman originates from the same IP as your browser. Apex runs from the server IP. So the cookie might be a red herring. Try the authorisation header

Comment: @stwissel Please can you elaborate more on the authorisation header? is it like this : req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth <accesstoken>');
If yes, how should i generate the access token?

Comment: @ShridharPuntambekar, did you ever get this figured out? I am also looking for a way to automate sending to Pardot based on specific criteria.